# SQL query to get last record based on table relation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, postgresql-13

i have 3 tables **boxes**, **stones** and **papers**; each box is related to a paper through a stone so my goal is to get the last box for each paper (boxes can share papers). have tried an ActiveRecord way to go in rails but could not use an aggregate function in a uuid coulmn so this does not work:

`Box.joins(:stone).group('stone.paper_id').maximum(:id).values`

im struggling going for a pure SQL statement since missing the stones table, i have the following:

```
select distinct on (papers.id) boxes.created_at, boxes.id 
from papers 
left join boxes on paper.id = boxes.id 
order by paper.id, boxes.created_at DESC;
```

all 3 tables primary keys are uuids together with other columns that are not relevant for the query since i just want as a return the uuids of the last box for each paper.

```
table:boxes
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                  id                  |      email      | delivered |           created_at            |               stone_id               |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 61a341b0-a147-4534-9368-fdbc7b61fc0c | test@test.com   | true      | Fri, 04 Mar 2022 00:19:31 +0000 | 7fda6668-e9b2-45b3-957a-fbdbcd833cd0 |
| c20f4b61-8606-4aa7-870a-29b9df9d9492 | test2@test.com  | true      | Thu, 24 Feb 2022 11:42:01 +0000 | cdb35b8a-b553-4095-8b14-e855ebdf5044 |
| 9202384f-1895-4f94-9972-3ef837655aae | test3@test.com  | false     | Thu, 10 Mar 2022 00:59:54 +0000 | bbd5dcbc-b38d-4751-aaac-2b3dd83c5545 |
+--------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+

table:stones
+--------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
|                  id                  | status | code |           created_at            |               paper_id               |
+--------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 7fda6668-e9b2-45b3-957a-fbdbcd833cd0 |      1 |    3 | Sun, 06 Mar 2022 12:58:56 +0000 | a0acba15-e321-4f9f-996f-a6c16e56300d |
| cdb35b8a-b553-4095-8b14-e855ebdf5044 |      1 |    4 | Thu, 03 Mar 2022 19:57:14 +0000 | a0acba15-e321-4f9f-996f-a6c16e56300d |
| bbd5dcbc-b38d-4751-aaac-2b3dd83c5545 |      2 |    5 | Fri, 11 Mar 2022 11:50:08 +0000 | de936cf2-c158-4961-9ef4-60affc4ff87f |
+--------------------------------------+--------+------+---------------------------------+--------------------------------------+

table:papers
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
|                  id                  | type |           created_at            |
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+
| a0acba15-e321-4f9f-996f-a6c16e56300d |    1 | Sat, 05 Mar 2022 05:59:00 +0000 |
| de936cf2-c158-4961-9ef4-60affc4ff87f |    5 | Thu, 03 Mar 2022 19:57:14 +0000 |
| 473a9dd4-3f38-49d0-8d1e-b5ab87e8ea92 |    4 | Sat, 12 Mar 2022 22:55:16 +0000 |
+--------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------+

box1 has a stone1 that relates to paper1
box2 has a stone2 that relates to paper1
box3 has a stone3 that relates to paper2
```

as a result i want **box1** and **box3** uuids since they are the most recent boxes (order by the time they were created) for each available paper, box2 is ignored since shares paper1 with box1 and it is not the most recent one. any help will be much appreciated! thanks in advance!

```
result:most recent boxes ids
+--------------------------------------+
|                  id                  |
+--------------------------------------+
| 61a341b0-a147-4534-9368-fdbc7b61fc0c |
| 9202384f-1895-4f94-9972-3ef837655aae |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: From  the `select distinct on` are you using `PostgreSQL` ?  If so please remove `MySQL` tag. As per the question add  table description, data examples and expected result in text format

Comment: Can you edit your post and add table description with sample datas and expected result

Comment: have just done it, let me know if it is better now

Comment: @jupcan read [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and update the question with proper information

Comment: `... each box is related to a paper through a stone ...` <<-- completely unclear. Please add the table definitions for all three tables.

Comment: oh that was my bad, im sorry and thanks @Philippe! have edited it right now!

Comment: It will be much easier if `created_at` would be proper date format

Comment: @ErgestBasha since data is inserted through rails models, its format is a DateTime one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this query ([Result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jcYabQomu1jSWUynGiJuB/0))

```
with x as (
select row_number() over (partition by p.id order by b.created_at desc) as rn,b.id as id_box,p.id as id_paper
from boxes b join stones s on b.stone_id = s.id
join papers p on p.id = s.paper_id)
select x.id_box from x where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cte` finds the latest `id` based on `paper_id` wich is related to  `papers` table . And then join with the `box` table.

Try and let me know if it helps:

```
with cte as 
    (
      select s.id,
             s.paper_id,row_number() over(partition by paper_id order by created_at desc ) as rn
      from stones s
    ) select b.id
      from boxes b 
      inner join cte c on c.id=b.stone_id
      inner join papers p on c.paper_id=p.id
      where c.rn=1
      order by b.created_at desc;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id
> 9202384f-1895-4f94-9972-3ef837655aae
> 61a341b0-a147-4534-9368-fdbc7b61fc0c
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=aa2b7cf2bd4acee597ff4af1b735b5c3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (p.id)
       b.id
  FROM boxes AS b
 INNER JOIN stones AS s
    ON s.id = b.stone_id
 INNER JOIN papers AS p
    ON p.id = s.paper_id
 ORDER BY p.id, b.created_at DESC
```

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b6974c8830e75bd5820557c3ef767846).

Answer (score 0):

*"SQL query to get last record based on table relation"*

There is no record in table, just logical rows grouped into page in any order. There is no default or specific order like a spreadsheet into a table page and rows are placed into the page as a heap. You must well understood that you will never ever have any way to find the last "record" !

In a database, you will find, only what you will store into. If **you** want to find the last row that **you** have inserted, **you** need to provide this information at the INSERT statement.

And I say **YOU**, because any other user can do the same inserts at the same time, with the same values... This is concurrency !

Now the question is "**what do you functionnaly want ?**"

Comment: data is inserted in postgresql tables through rails models, thats why i want to then query last records (the ones created recently) as explained, did my best to provide as much info as possible

Comment: Whatever the application/code/language you are using Rail, Python, C, Fortran, C#, Java or any framework or ORM, the result will be the same : rows are inserted via a SQL INSERT statement and the database storage engine will arrange the rows where it sees fit and not in the order of arrival

Comment: but each record has a created_at column value representing that order in rails

Comment: but you can have the same value of columns "created_at" when inserting many rows at one time, or by the fact that two different user will inserts a single row at the same time... So this artifact column does not serves you for your requirement !